# How to let vim use relative line numbers counting from 1 instead of 0

Tags: vim

I've been exploring vim some more in order to be able to use it better and while doing so, I've re-activated the showing of the line numbers with the relative line numbers active.

So my .vimrc contains following lines:

```
" Set line-numbers
set nu
set relativenumber
```

This all works nicely, though vim starts counting the current line from 0, while I like it to count from 1.

So currently it looks like this:

```
 2 " Something else
 1 
3  " Set line-numbers
 1 set nu
 2 set relativenumber
```

Note: The 3 is the current line number.

Let's assume that I like to cut my line number config, I have to use the command *3dd* while the relative line number states *2*. Does anyone know how to change this to:

```
 3 " Something else
 2 
3  " Set line-numbers
 2 set nu
 3 set relativenumber
```

JVApen

Comment: I think most people use relative line numbers with `j` and `k` and a count: `d2j` and `d2k`. Then the numbers are just right.

Comment: I guess I'm not most people :( Somehow I don't use hjkl that often

Comment: @glts Yes, I agree, but still I find a bit weird the fact that doing `3dd` and `d3j` give a different result by one line. I mean, I understand that they are different commands, but I feel like they should be interchangeable without having to think "oh I should add +1 to do what I want to do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counting is built into Vim's core; you'd have to change the source code and recompile your custom binary. Alternatively, there's the [RltvNmbr.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2351), which emulates the setting in Vimscript. By modifying that, you'd avoid the recompilation, but only get an emulation that's far from perfect. Better adapt to Vim's way of counting :-)

Comment: From what I can find, also this extension counts from 0, though off course it will be easier to adapt. A bit unfortunate that it's not supported by default (both by vim as the extension) though I guess I'll have to adapt instead of configuring my tools :(

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. The plugin is easier to modify, but still I would recommend to rather adapt to the current behavior.